# Google Places API nearby search return different result when executed from Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, google-places-api

I'm trying to use the Google Places API inside an API which is currently running on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk, and it works well in most cases, but i've found some examples in which the API acts strange. This is one such example:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=[API_KEY]&radius=300&location=-3.7411363,-38.4717768&keyword=boto center

this is the result when i execute the GET request from postman in my computer:

```
{
   "html_attributions": [],
   "results": [
      {
         "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
         "geometry": {
            "location": {
               "lat": -3.741095,
               "lng": -38.4729603
            },
            "viewport": {
               "northeast": {
                  "lat": -3.739996920107278,
                  "lng": -38.47135937010728
               },
               "southwest": {
                  "lat": -3.742696579892721,
                  "lng": -38.47405902989272
               }
            }
         },
         "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id": "a916c330a37073aab32ffb486649e541af5b4038",
         "name": "BotoCenter: Centro de Estética, Aplicação de Toxina Botulínica Rio Mar Fortaleza",
         "opening_hours": {
            "open_now": true
         },
         "photos": [
            {
               "height": 636,
               "html_attributions": [
                  "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110215894449097941694\">A Google User</a>"
               ],
               "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAOuF4uwh5t4gS9Hx_-AzzbrC9l2OVA_eRC_ffBu6NUHzJQzY3LC8EQ2uY3Bvz0oo_eQvKShVbUzujEyf4_zRHES4UJ1gq8a4xVl_SPjZ2By2NYBebsxzUHGYJPTM5at-TEhBqZ89uEeJLRpnxBs1VoDCGGhRtK6gcdonrUJvWC0ckbyxmUZA9qQ",
               "width": 510
            }
         ],
         "place_id": "ChIJdyhrcpxHxwcRoKDSIYX7AYg",
         "plus_code": {
            "compound_code": "7G5G+HR Papicu, Fortaleza - State of Ceará",
            "global_code": "69837G5G+HR"
         },
         "rating": 0,
         "reference": "ChIJdyhrcpxHxwcRoKDSIYX7AYg",
         "scope": "GOOGLE",
         "types": [
            "health",
            "point_of_interest",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total": 0,
         "vicinity": "R. Des. Lauro Nogueira, 1500 - Papicu, Fortaleza"
      }
   ],
   "status": "OK"
}
```

And this is the result from the same request when it is executed inside my Elastic BeanStalk:

```
{ html_attributions: [], results: [], status: 'ZERO_RESULTS' }
```

Any idea what is going on or what i'm doing wrong?

If location is relevant, i currently reside in northeast Brazil and my EBS instance is in North Virginia.